# Escaping dollar sign when echo write to file in CentOS linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, nginx, heredoc

I am working on a bash script that needs to create a file in this location:

**/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo**

with the following contents:

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

So, I have tried to do it like this:

```
cat >/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo <<EOL
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/\$releasever/\$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOL
```

When I check the contents of the file, I see the following:

[image]

As you can see, the dollar sign weren't getting escaped, so the variable was evaluated to null/empty string and the contents do not look correct. Because, when I try to install nginx, I get this error:

> http://nginx.org/packages/centos///repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle, it suffices to use a syntax

```
cat >file <<EOL
$my_var
EOL
```

That is, use the vars as they are, without escaping `$`.

So instead of

```
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/\$releasever/\$basearch/
                                         ^            ^
```

say

```
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
```

From `man bash`:

> **Here Documents**
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
>   current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no
>   trailing blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are
>   then used as the standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>       <<[-]word
>               here-document
>       delimiter
> ```
>
> No  parameter  expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion,
>   or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any characters in word
>   are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and
>   the lines in  the  here-document are not expanded.  **If word is
>   unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter
>   expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion**.  In the
>   latter case, the character sequence \ is ignored,  and  \ 
>   must  be used to quote the characters \, $, and `.

See an example:

```
$ cat a.sh
r="hello"
cat - <<EOL
hello
$r
EOL

echo "double quotes"
cat - <<"EOL"
hello
$r
EOL

echo "single quotes"
cat - <<'EOL'
hello
$r
EOL
```

And let's run it:

```
$ bash a.sh
hello
hello              <-- it expands when unquoted
double quotes
hello
$r                 <-- it does not expand with "EOL"
single quotes
hello
$r                 <-- it does not expand with 'EOL'
```

Comment: The single quotes one doesn't actually use single quotes ;)

Answer (score 4):

There's an *here-doc* generic syntax to prevent the content to be expanded like when you put single quotes around variables :

```
cat<<'EOF'
```

:

```
cat<<'EOF' > /path/to/file
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOF
```

From

```
man bash | less +/here-doc
```

> If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the  here-document  are not  expanded.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap that string into single quotes

```
baseurl='http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/'
```

Then the dollar sign would be treated as a usual character.

```
[root@xxx ~]# cat test
baseurl='http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/'
```

Comment: I need to write multi-line as per example in question, not single lines.